# Storing assignments between 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering what is the best solutions to store relations between 2 tables in mysql.

I have following structure

```
Table: categories

 id   | name           | etc...
_______________________________
 1    | Graphic cards  | ...
 2    | Processors     | ...
 3    | Hard Drives    | ...

Table: properties_of_categories

id    | name     
_____________________
 1    | Capacity
 2    | GPU Speed
 3    | Memory size
 4    | Clock rate
 5    | Cache
```

Now I need them to have connections, and question is what is a better, more efficient and lighter solution, which is important because there may be hundreds of categories and thousands of properties assigned to them.

Should I just create another table with a structure like

```
categoryId | propertyId
```

Or perhaps add another column to categories table and store properties in text field like 1,7,19,23

Or maybe create json files named for example 7.json with content like

```
{1,7,19,23}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is better when it comes to relational databases. You should create a table that will pair each category to multiple properties (1:n relationship)

You could structure the table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE categories_properties_match(
    categoryId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    propertyId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(categoryId, propertyId),
    FOREIGN KEY(categoryId) REFERENCES categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(propertyId) REFERENCES properties_of_categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The primary key ensures that there will be no duplicate entries, that means entries that match one category to the same property twice

Comment: Wow I just learnt something new. I didn't know about CASCADE. Thanks for help I'll use your solution.

Answer (score 2):

As this question is pertaining to Relational World, I would suggest to add another table to store many to many relationship between Category and Property.

You can also use JSON column to store many values in one of the table.

JSON Datatype is introduced in MYSQL 5.7 and it comes with various features for JSON data retrieval and updation. However if you are using older version, you would need to manage it with string column with some cumbersome queries for string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

The required structure depends on the relationship type: one-to-many, many-to-one, or many-to-many (M2M).

For a one-to-many, a foreign key (FK) on the 'many' side relates many items to the 'one' side. The reverse is correct for many-to-one.

For many-to-many (M2M) you need an intermediate relational (or junction) table exactly as you suggest. This allows you to "reuse" both categories and properties in any combinations. However it's slightly more SQL - requiring 2 JOINs.

If you are looking for performance, then using FKs to primary keys (PKs) would be very efficient and the queries are pretty simple. Using JSON would presumably require you to parse in PHP and construct on-the-fly second queries which would multiply your coding work and testing, data transfer, CPU overhead, and limit scalability.

In your case I'm guessing that both "graphics cards" and "hard drives" could have e.g. "memory size" plus other properties, so you would need a M2M relational table as you suggest.

As long as your keys are indexed (which PKs are), your JOIN to this relational table will be very quick and efficient.

If you use CONSTRAINTs with your relations, they you ensure you maintain data integrity: you cannot delete a category to which a property is "attached". This is a good feature in the long run.

Hundreds and thousands of records is a tiny amount for MySQL. You would use this technique even with millions of records. So there's no worry about size.

RDBMS databases are designed specifically to do this, so I would recommend using the native features than try to do it yourself in JSON. (unless I'm missing some new JSON MySQL feature! *)

* Since posting this, I indeed stumbled across [a new JSON MySQL feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). It seems, from a quick read, you could implement all sorts of new structures and relations using JSON and virtual column keys, possibly removing the need for junction tables. This will probably blur the line between MySQL as an RDBMS and NoSQL.

Comment: Wow that was comprehensive answer. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. dimlucas's answer is right, I just told you more "why" it's the right choice. I'd be cautious with cascading deletes! They work, but you typically need application logic to ensure the deletion is what you want.